# Python - Code is in inspect but not in bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

So basically what I want to do is that I want to check from Nike (Just took an exampel where there is a event and check what it says for each event) and basically for me it does say "**YOU'RE ALREADY ON THE WAITLIST**" but if you win it will tell you that you have won. Basically what I wanted to do is to see if I have won using requests so far what I have done is:

```
testare = "https://www.nike.com/events-registration/event?id=91858"
rq = ses.get(testare)
soup = bs(rq.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
print(soup.find('h3', {'class': 'nsg-font-family'}))
sys.exit()
```

however there is not this piece of code when I search with soup at all (Which I mean there isn't etc *nsg-font-family--platform ng-binding* at all if I do req.text or print soup)

```
<h3 class="nsg-font-family--platform ng-binding" ng-bind-html="eventData.eventErrorHeader">You're already on the waitlist</h3>
```

which there is in Nike when I inspect the code with F12. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like the class to find is `nsg-font-family--platform`

Comment: Exactly like I did, but whenever I do it it just says 'None' - When I print out the whole soup - the nsg-font is not there.

Comment: the content is loaded through javascript, i think you need a different tool to scrape this

Comment: Possible.. Is there any tip?

Comment: selenium might work for this purpose